# RegisterExternalEvaluator claims MissingDependencies even though ZMQ is installed

Tags: external-calls, python

I have an Anaconda Python installation in a non-standard location. So I ran

```
RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python", "path-to-python.exe"]
```

But I got the following error message:

```
StartExternalSession::depend: The installation does not have the required dependencies.
```

[image: RegisterExternalEvaluator]

But the only dependency that is listed for Python is ZMQ, which is installed:

[image: Python zmq]

Any idea how I can get `RegisterExternalEvaluator` to recognise the fact that ZMQ is installed in Python?

Comment: I wonder if the problem is that `pyzmq` is installed through `conda` instead of through `pip`. That really should not be the problem, should it?

Comment: have you tried installing jupyter? I was had one conda environment that would register, the other would not, giving the same errors as you see. Then I noticed I had jupyter and ipykernel installed on the working environment, so I installed them in the other.  This fixed it for me.

Comment: @JasonB.I do have Jupyter installed in that environment. Since I am running low on time, I have decided to go nuclear and create a Flask web service in Python, which I will call from Wolfram Language. All this, of course, while I wait for SAS in the next version of `Mathematica`!

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to [`workflow/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html) in the help.

Then install the "pyzmq" package for communicating with Python.

If Python is not found after executing `FindExternalEvaluators["Python"]` , you may need to register Python manually like `RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python","D:\\Python27\\python2.exe"]`.

Comment: As indicated by the screen shot in the question, I have tried `RegisterExternalEvaluate`. The problem is that the function thinks that ZMQ is missing even though it is installed in Python.

Comment: If you can't solve the problem by trying to use the path of "D:\\Python3\\Python37-32\\python.exe" format, you may need to wait for other people in the community to answer this question.

Comment: There is no difference between the formats `"C:\\path\\to\\python.exe"` and `FileNameJoin[{"C:", "path", "to", "python.exe"}]`. I always prefer the latter because then the code is platform-independent.