# How can I import datasets from TensorFlow datasets into mathematica?

Tags: notebooks, python, data-acquisition

TensorFlow datasets are available at https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets. I wonder if there's a way to directly import any of those datasets directly into Mathematica 12.
I tried

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "import tensorflow_datasets as tfds"]
```

However, I receive a number of errors, mainly about missing zmq. So, I went back and installed zmq with

```
pip install pyzmq
```

zymq install seems fine because if I issue the command again, I receive the following outptut

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (20.0.0)
```

When I try FindExternalEvaluate, it seems to recognize many versions of Python on my system, however 3.8 still seems to be missing the zmq link

[image: FindExternalEvaluate output]

I am not sure how to proceed to fix this error and then move to the real task of importing tensorflow datasets. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216061/7167)?

Comment: I had to set up python using `RegisterExternalEvaluator`  with a target pointing to the appropriate python executable.  `FindExternalEvaluators["Python"]` returns that python is registered, which allows me to run your `ExternalEvaluate` code without errors (save that I only have the dataset installed, not tensorflow).